# Microsoft Teams Graph API - When list members of an external chat, can not get name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In Teams, I have chat with someone whose not in my team. And when I use Graph API to list chat members, its response contains two members, and the response like this (I use '*' covered real id):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('73445b6****************90c35f525a')/chats('19%3A73********************f525a_d1307158-d331-488e-9198-4a01ca7a508d%40unq.gbl.spaces')/members",
    "@odata.count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "id": "d130715*******************01ca7a508d",
            "roles": [],
            "displayName": null,
            "userId": "d130715*******************01ca7a508d",
            "email": null
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "id": "73445********************5f525a",
            "roles": [],
            "displayName": "my name",
            "userId": "73445********************5f525a",
            "email": null
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see that the other member's name is null. But I do see his name in Teams Desktop App.

Since I get his ID, so I tried https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/d130715*******************01ca7a508d

but response says it doesn't exist.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource 'd130715*******************01ca7a508d' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-10-20T05:55:57",
            "request-id": "48fb241e-7ee5-4498-9eda-8642b4b1b499",
            "client-request-id": "40591cf1-ff64-f1d1-e658-a90dc7665ade"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can get the member's name of an external chat?

Comment: Do we see the issue only if its external chat or internal chat too?

Comment: I see this issue only when list members of external chats.

Comment: The error points that it can't find the member in the given chart; i suspect it most probably the external user who's part of the chat. Instead you can give a try getting their email address. I am not sure whether the external users name is enabled at this point.

Comment: @Dev Yes, this chat has two members, and one of them is in another team. So the chat has an external mark. when I list members of this chat, I can get both of their id, but the one who's in another team, I can't get his name as well as his email. I'm sorry that I didn't get how to get their email address with only an user id. Every time I use /users/id/**, the response shows 'Resource *** does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.' Could you show me an example?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Yes, I try it just now, and still have the issue.

Comment: For External users the display name will be null,  This is by design.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Thank for your reply. However, does it mean there is no way to get the member's name of an external chat? Or... the external member's other information? I'm wondering if there's a way to get some external chat's info(no topic) to identify it when displaying to customers, because we actually could send message to that chat..

Comment: Currently you cannot get the user name using graph API. This is by design.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Maybe we will just ignore external chats. Thanks a lot for your comments

Answer (score 1):

Currently You cannot get the external user name using the graph API. This is by design.